# Multilevel ordering with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
tdf <- structure(list(GO = c("Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction", 
"Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction|Endocytosis", "I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling", 
"NF-kappa B signaling pathway", "NF-kappaB import into nucleus", 
"T cell chemotaxis"), PosCount = c(17, 18, 4, 5, 1, 2), shortgo = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("z", "X", "y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("GO", 
"PosCount", "shortgo"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like this:

```
                                                  GO PosCount shortgo
1             Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction       17       z
2 Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction|Endocytosis       18       z
3                I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling        4       X
4                       NF-kappa B signaling pathway        5       X
5                      NF-kappaB import into nucleus        1       X
6                                  T cell chemotaxis        2       y
```

What I want to do then is to first sort  by `shortgo` alphabetically - case insensitive - and then for each `shortgo` group internally sort by `PosCount`. Yielding this:

```
                                                  GO PosCount shortgo
                       NF-kappa B signaling pathway        5       X
                I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling        4       X
                      NF-kappaB import into nucleus        1       X
                                  T cell chemotaxis        2       y
 Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction|Endocytosis       18       z
             Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction       17       z
```

But why this doesn't work:

```
library(dplyr)
tdf[order(tdf$shortgo),]
tdf <- tdf %>% group_by(shortgo) %>% arrange(desc(PosCount))
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is to combine them into one call. Though you'll need to convert `shortgo` to `character` class first (see below for explanation)

```
tdf %>% 
    arrange(as.character(shortgo), desc(PosCount))
#                                                   GO PosCount shortgo
# 1                       NF-kappa B signaling pathway        5       x
# 2                I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling        4       x
# 3                      NF-kappaB import into nucleus        1       x
# 4                                  T cell chemotaxis        2       y
# 5 Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction|Endocytosis       18       z
# 6             Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction       17       z
```

---

So the reason you'll need to convert to character is because `shortgo` is a factor which is basically an `integer` vector with a `levels` attribute. So `order` uses these integers in order to order your vector. In your case the integers don't correspond to the correct order of the levels

```
tdf$shortgo
## [1] z z x x x y
## Levels: z x y
as.numeric(tdf$shortgo)
## [1] 1 1 2 2 2 3
```

So you can see that `z` is coded as 1, `x` is coded as 2 and `y` as 3 while it should be 3, 2, 1. Thus `sort` returns "wrong" result

```
sort(tdf$shortgo)
# 1] z z x x x y
# Levels: z x y
```

Compare to

```
test <- factor(sort(as.character(tdf$shortgo)))
sort(test)
## [1] x x x y z z
## Levels: x y z
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `order` base `R`:

```
with(tdf, tdf[order(tolower(shortgo), -PosCount),])

#                                                  GO PosCount shortgo
#4                       NF-kappa B signaling pathway        5       X
#3                I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling        4       X
#5                      NF-kappaB import into nucleus        1       X
#6                                  T cell chemotaxis        2       y
#2 Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction|Endocytosis       18       z
#1             Cytokine-cytokine receptor interaction       17       z
```

Comment: Just a note here, `tolower` doesn't play any role other than converting `factor` to `character`